# Can we use Mechanize and Selenium WebDriver together? Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, nokogiri, mechanize

I know how to use selenium and nokogiri, it seems like:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :browser
driver.get "http://example.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)

...
```

But, if i need to use selenium with mechanize, it's possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Check the documentation for [Mechanize::Page.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/aai10-mechanize-2.0.1.0/Mechanize/Page.html)'s parameters

> new(uri=nil, response=nil, body=nil, code=nil, mech=nil)

So:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = Mechanize::Page.new URI.parse('http://example.com'), [], driver.page_source, 200, agent
```

Comment: Thank you! Also question, can we give the page source from mechanize to driver?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm more used to Watir::Webdriver (and you probably should be too)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, Watir more interesting, thank you!
And I have one more question.. Did you know how to save an image that generated by cookies, using Watir? or how to give page_source from Mechanize to Watir driver?

Comment: You need to start a new question for that, but make sure it hasn't been asked already first